# Get all connected device information

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, device

I want to get all information of connected devices as the below picture using C# (device name, location, status is required).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cFXs.png

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve using WMI.
You need to install System.Management from nuget.

[Computer System Hardware Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/computer-system-hardware-classes)

Here is an example of getting keyboard information.
It is unclear how Location is obtained, but it is probably determined from the DeviceID string.

```cs
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

internal class Program
{
    [SupportedOSPlatform("windows5.0")]
    private static void Main()
    {
        var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");
        var query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Keyboard");
        using (var sercher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
        using (var queryCollection = sercher.Get())
        {
            foreach (var o in queryCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o["Description"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(o["Status"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(o["DeviceID"].ToString());
                o.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could I get device name (Symbol barcode scanner) by DeviceID  (USB Input device) in C#?  My situation is: get all USB port (USB Input device, USB Root Hub (USB 3.0), etc) in PC and show in combobox. When user select any item, app will check if that USB port is connected with any device. If yes, I want to get the device name.

Comment: I think I can get it if the device is connected, but I don't know how to determine if it is a barcode scanner. Get the device information and try it out.